# Web services integration between Maximo and outside systems

Tags: web-services, maximo

In Maximo I have the ability to define an object structure (based on a Maximo table) and create a publish channel based on that structure to a specified endpoint (in my case I want it to be a web service endpoint).

My question now is how are the fields mapped on the web service endpoint?
E.g let's say I'm sending ID,TYPE,DESCRIPTION field values. How will it know which operation on the endpoint to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Maximo 7.5, go to Integration > Object Structures

[image: Object Structures]

Open your Object Structure > Select Action > Add/Modify Alias

By default, the Alias will typically be the same as the attribute (usually the database field name).

[image]

In my example of D-PERSON table, you can edit the Alias Name as you wish. I recommend staying with alphanumeric field names only if you can.

[image]

The D-PERSON example is from [Bruno Portaluri - Flat CSV file export with Maximo Integration Framework - April 2013](http://maximodev.blogspot.com/2013/04/flat-csv-file-export-maximo-integration-framework.html)